# Timeout in expect

Tags: tcl, expect

Trying to automate a ssh process.  The prompt I got when ssh into a host is:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-2-110:~$
```

My expect script

```
spawn ssh ubuntu@a.b.c.d
expect ":~\$ "
```

This will timeout while waiting for the pattern.

However, if I change the expect statement to be

```
expect "\$ "
```

it works fine (no wait).

Wonder why.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out the the ":" and "~" in the prompt `:~$` is colored in the terminal.

Found that the following expect statement works (it results in a match)

```
expect -re ":.{8}~.{5}\\\$ "
```

Comment: Sometimes it helps to set the terminal type (`TERM` environment variable) to something that doesn't support colour, such as (classic) `vt100`.